# Ubuntu 14.10 blank screen between Grub menu and sign on screen

Tags: 14.10

Previously I had the Ubuntu logo displayed with alternating colour timing dots after selecting Ubuntu from GRUB now I have a blank screen until the log on as a user screen. Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 0):

[See my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/542342/cant-open-ubuntu-after-upgrade-to-14-10/542370#542370). There are many questions about video problems with 14.10. Problems with graphic card brands ranging from ATI, AMD, Intel, and NVidia.